# Gram-Schmidt over GF$(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, cryptography, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

I am reading the paper [The Steganographic File System](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/stego-fs.pdf) by Ross Anderson, Roger Needham, and Adi Shamir. On page 4, paragraph 2, the authors write:

> Finally, we use the Gram-Schmidt method to orthonormalise all the
>   vectors from $i$ onwards by subtracting from the candidate $K_i$ all
>   its components along later $K_j$ which the user knows by the chaining
>   property of the $p_j$’s.

This simply means that the authors use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm with the ground field GF$(2)$, and from the context, each of the original vectors the algorithm is applied to has norm $1$. However, in this case the algorithm produces a basis which is not necessarily orthonormal, not even orthogonal. Am I right? Is this a serious flaw?

Answer (score 5):

The answer below was posted before the piece of information about all the participating vectors get tagged with random bits to make sure their weights are odd.

---

IMHO a more serious problem with using Gram-Schmidt over $GF(2)$ is that Gram-Schmidt may call for division by zero! This is because in the projection formula
$$
y\mapsto y-\frac{(y,x)}{(x,x)}x
$$
the denominator $(x,x)$ vanishes when $x$ is orthogonal to itself.

For example consider the following subspace of $GF(2)^3$:
$$
V=\{(a,b,c)\in GF(2)^3\mid a+b+c=0\}.
$$
You will quickly realize that **every** vector of $V$ is orthogonal to itself.
Have fun trying to Gram-Schmidt orthogonalize e.g. the basis $v_1=(1,1,0)$,
$v_2=(1,0,1)$ of $V$ :-)

Comment: A careful look at the entire paragraph in question shows that you've hit the nail squarely on the head: "We now map each $p_i$ into a random
binary vector with an odd number of $1$’s (so that its dot product with itself is
$1$)."

Comment: You are right; I forgot to indicate that all the original vectors are of norm $1$. I will edit my post now.

Comment: Even if the participating vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m$ have odd Hamming weight, couldn't you have some $u_j$ have even Hamming weight? If so, won't that lead to division by zero at the later steps of computing $u_{j+1}, \dots, u_{m}$ as the Gram-Schmidt process continues?

Comment: Assume $v_1 = 10^{n-1}$, $v_2 = 1110^{n-3}$. Then $u_2 = v_2 - v_1 = 0110^{n-3}$. How do you proceed from there?